# dplyr::select - programatically rearrange columns using character variable for column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to re-arrange the columns of a df using `dplyr::select` programatically
A non R user is going to execute the code and this person will provide two inputs as follows:

```
report.month <- "Jul"
report.year  <- 2017
```

Only the month will change, all other names in the df will be the same

## df that I want to re-arrange looks as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
     country = "AU",
    Jul_2017 = 500,
    Customer = "some guy")
```

## This is the output that I want

```
  country Customer Jul_2017
       AU some guy      500
```

## This is what I tried, which does not work and I have run out of ideas:

```
    reporting.month.name <- as.symbol(paste(report.month, report.year, sep = "_"))

    df1 %>% select(country, Customer, reporting.month.name)
Error: `reporting.month.name` must resolve to integer column positions, not a symbol
```

Any advice/help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the as.symbol() from your code, like this:

```
reporting.month.name <- paste(report.month, report.year, sep = "_")

df1 %>% select(country, Customer, reporting.month.name)
```

Output:

```
  country Customer Jul_2017
1      AU some guy      500
```

Comment: Thanks! I also tried `select(contains(reporting.month.name))`, which worked for me

Comment: @cephalopod - Oh okay, good. I'll try to keep that option in mind too next time.